# CSSのmin-widthとmax-widthに同じ値を指定する利点

Tags: css

初歩的なことでしたら大変恐縮なのですが、
`min-width`と`max-width`が同じ値の実装をたまに見かけるものの、
この書き方は何か利点があるのでしょうか。

例えば

```
min-width: 35px;
max-width: 35px;
```

とある場合、シンプルに

```
width: 35px;
```

とした方が変更も簡単だと思います。
（今回はtableのtdでこのような書き方を見つけました）

例えば`width`だけだと制約が弱く変更されてしまう場合があるとすれば、
どのような場合に変更されてしまうのかの例を教えて頂けるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

どこかから`min-width`や`max-width`を継承するのを警戒しての事ではないでしょうか。
（こういった配慮が必要になるかは、CSS の設計によると思います）

下記スニペットの例ですと、CSS側では`.xx`への指定として`width: 5em;`を指定しています。
しかし、HTML側で`.xx`が付いているのは`p`要素ですから、`p`へのスタイル指定の`min-width: 10em;`も有効です。
この場合`min-width`に制約され、`width`は`10em`より小くならないという事になります。
`.yy`の方は`min-width`の指定があるので、`p`への指定を上書き出来ています。

```css
p {
 min-width: 10em;
 color: white;
 background: green;
}
.xx {
 width: 5em;
 background: darkblue;
}
.yy {
 min-width: 5em;
 max-width: 5em;
 background: darkred;
}
```

```html
<p>あいうえお。かきくけこ。</p>
<p class="xx">あいうえお。かきくけこ。</p>
<p class="yy">あいうえお。かきくけこ。</p>
```